# Python - Lista de colores desordenados y repetidos

Tags: python

Buenas, estoy haceindo un programa que tiene una lista de colores repetidos y desordenados. Deseo saber cual de esos colores es el más se repite y en su caso retornar el color más repetido y el numero de veces. Hay una particularidad, si hay varios colores con el máximo numero la prioridad de la lista sería: azul, rojo,verde y amarillo.

Para poder hacerlo he pensado en crear una funcion con 2 listas:

1 Lista con colores desordenados y repetidos.

2.Lista con prioridad.

De esta forma me puedo recorrer la los elementos de la lista 2 y así ver cuantas veces se repite.

Mi programa empezaba así pero me he atascado y no se como continuarlo:

```
def color_frecuente(lista):

    lista2 =["azul","rojo","verde","amarillo"]

    print lista2

    contador = 0

    for i in lista2:
        for j in colores:
            if i == j:
                contador += 1
        return (i,contador)


# bloque principal

colores = ['azul', 'rojo', 'verde', 'verde', 'verde', 'rojo', 'verde', 'verde', 'azul', 'amarillo', 'azul',
            'azul', 'verde', 'verde', 'verde', 'amarillo']
print color_frecuente(colores)
```

Me podéis echar una mano?

Gracias.

Comment: Francisco ¿Puedes usar cualquier característica del lenguaje o estás limitado por alguna razón? `collections.Counter` es lo adecuado para estas cosas por lo general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el siguiente codigo se muestra primero calcular un diccionario que almacena la cantidad de veces que se repite cada color, despues calculamos los maximos, y si existen varios colores que tienen la misma cantidad del maximo aplicamos calculamos el maximo de ese subconjunto respecto a su posicion.

```
def obtener_color_frecuente(colores, lista_prioridad):
    contador = {}
    for color in colores:
        if color in contador:
            contador[color] += 1 # incrementamos si existe el color
        else:
            contador[color] = 1 # creamos un nuevo item con el key del color y el valor inicial de 1
    m = max(contador.values()) # obtenemos el max de repeticiones
    color_seleccionado = [key for key, value in contador.items() if value == m] # seleccionamos los colores que cumplen con el maximo
    if len(color_seleccionado) > 1: # verificamos si existe mas de un maximo
        color_seleccionado = min(color_seleccionado, key= lambda x: lista_prioridad.index(x)) # obtenemos el elemento segun la prioridad
    else:
         color_seleccionado = color_seleccionado[0]
    return color_seleccionado, m

prioridad = ["azul","rojo","verde","amarillo"]
colores = ['azul', 'rojo', 'verde', 'verde', 'verde', 'rojo', 'verde', 'verde', 'azul', 'amarillo', 'azul',
        'azul', 'verde', 'verde', 'verde', 'amarillo']
print(obtener_color_frecuente(colores, prioridad))
```

Comment: El programa devuelve el color más repetido pero no el número de veces que se repite.

Comment: @FRANCISCOJAVIERVEGASFERNAND Ya lo corregi

Comment: Ahora sí, pero hay una forma de que el resultado sea "verde",8 y  no salga  ['verde'], 8

Comment: Prueba devuelta

Comment: Al ejecutar el programa me sale el siguiente errorRespuesta incorrecta 
RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 11: color_seleccionado = min(color_seleccionado, key= lambda x: lista_prioridad.index(x))) RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 11: color_seleccionado = min(color_seleccionado, key= lambda x: lista_prioridad.index(x)) .NameError: name 'lista_prioridad' is not defined )

Comment: def color_frecuente(lista):
    contador = {}
    for color in lista:
        if color in contador:
            contador[color] += 1
        else:
            contador[color] = 1
    m = max(contador.values())
    color_seleccionado = [key for key, value in contador.items() if value == m]
    if len(color_seleccionado) > 1:

Comment: color_seleccionado = min(color_seleccionado, key= lambda x: lista_prioridad.index(x))
    else:
         color_seleccionado = color_seleccionado[0]
    return color_seleccionado, m

prioridad = ["azul","rojo","verde","amarillo"]
lista = ["azul", "rojo", "verde", "verde", "verde", "rojo", "verde", "verde", "azul", "amarillo", "azul",
        "azul", "verde", "verde", "verde", "amarillo"]
print(color_frecuente(lista))

Comment: Modifique tu programa porque me pedían un solo argumento para la función def color_frecuente

Comment: Copie mi codigo como estas, no voy a modicarlo, si usted desea hacerle modificaciones hagala a la copia mia, si tiene otros problemas solucionelos, estoy ocupado en este momento, y mi ayuda ya llego a su fin.

Comment: ¿No hay otra forma de definir la linea:color_seleccionado = min(color_seleccionado, key= lambda x: lista_prioridad.index(x))?

Comment: Si sabe algo de programacion podrias definir lista_prioridad dentro de la funcion como muestra su codigo inicial, si quieres cambiar de nombre, cambielos a todos, disculpe pero no tengo tiempo para hacer tutoria

Answer (score 1):

Hola igual estoy comenzando a programar y inente elaborar un codigo mas corto con lo que obtuve esta posible solicion, por favor analiza las situaciones logicas.
lo he probado y respeta el orden de prioridades, espero alguien me pueda apoyar con comentarios de retroalimentacion,(ya que no funciona si un color que no esta definido previamente se agrega) gracias.

```
`def color_frecuente(lista):
    a = lista.count("azul")
    b = lista.count("rojo")
    c = lista.count("amarillo")
    d = lista.count("verde")
    if a >= b and a >= c and a >= d:
        max = "azul", a
    elif b > a and b >= c and b >= d:
        max = "rojo", b
    elif c > a and c > b and c > d:
        max = "amarillo", c
    elif d > a and d > b and d >= c:
        max = "verde", d
    return max`
```

Comment: Hola Héctor, bienvenido, tu respuesta es correcta, aunque no responde al formato del sitio (mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)), tiene un pequeño inconveniente que aparece cuando la cantidad de elementos a verificar es grande, el bloque if/ elif sería gigante, igual, para lo que se pidió, me gusta, te recomiendo que mires las otras respuestas, para ver los distintos enfoques, y ver que te puede servir.

Comment: Para evitar votos negativos, edita tu pregunta y explica como funciona tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como te comentó @FjSevilla puedes usar [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) para generar básicamente una tabla de frecuencias

```
from collections import Counter

colores = ['azul', 'rojo', 'verde', 'verde', 'verde', 'rojo', 'verde',
        'verde', 'azul', 'amarillo', 'azul', 'azul', 'verde', 'verde', 'verde', 'amarillo',
        'azul','azul','azul','azul']

# Diccionario para configurar el orden adicional   
order={"azul":1, "rojo": 2, "verde": 3, "amarillo":4}

lista = sorted(list(Counter(colores).items()),key=lambda x: (-x[1], order[x[0]]))

print(lista)
print(lista[0])
```

La salida

```
[('azul', 8), ('verde', 8), ('rojo', 2), ('amarillo', 2)] # Lista completa
('azul', 8)                                               # El primer elemento
```

- Modifique la lista de ejemplos (`colores`) para probar completamente el orden que esperas
- `Counter(colores)` genera un diccionario con cada color y su cantidad de ocurrencias
- Lo transformamos en una lista con `list()`
- Y la ordenamos mediante `sorted()`, la función `lambda` establece como va a a ser el orden, en primer lugar la cantidad de ocurrencias descendente `-x[1]` y en segundo el orden definido mediante el diccionario creado especialmente `order`

Comment: El programa devuleve lo esperado pero to estoy algo limitado ya que no puedo usar librerias. Debo escribir una funcion que reciba un argumento lista y que retorne el color más repetido y el número de veces. Siempre teniendo en cuenta la prioridad.

Answer (score 0):

Aca te mando una posible solución:
...

```
lista = ["azul","rojo","verde","verde","verde","rojo","verde","verde","azul","amarillo","azul","azul","verde","verde","verde","amarillo","amarillo"]

def  color_frecuente(lista):
   lista2 = ["azul", "rojo", "verde", "amarillo"]
   nueva_lista = []
   for i in lista2:
       cantidad = 0
       for j in lista:
           if i == j:
               cantidad = cantidad + 1
       nueva_lista.append([cantidad, i])

   az = nueva_lista.pop(0)
   rj = nueva_lista.pop(0)
   vr = nueva_lista.pop(0)
   am = nueva_lista.pop(0)

   if ((az[0]>=rj[0])and(az[0]>=vr[0])and(az[0]>=am[0])):
       return (az[1],az[0])
   elif ((rj[0]>az[0])and(rj[0]>=vr[0])and(rj[0]>=am[0])):
       return (rj[1],rj[0])
   elif ((vr[0]>az[0]) and (vr[0]>rj[0]) and (vr[0]>=am[0])):
       return (vr[1], vr[0])
   elif ((am[0]>az[0])and(am[0]>rj[0])and(am[0]>vr[0])):
       return (am[1],am[0])

print(color_frecuente(lista))
```

...

Comment: Hola @Luis. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla. Por otra parte, también puede consultar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) o leer todo sobre «[respondiendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)»

Comment: Recuerda que debes explicar el código que has publicado en tu respuesta para ayudar a otras personas a entender lo que propones como solución.